# Как искать соответствия в таблице и выводить их списком в одной клетке?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, таблицы

Есть 2 листа на страничке. на одном список продуктов и на втором места где эти продукты можно найти
[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне на 1 листе в столбце B вывести все места где можно найти предметы?
Например в B2 написать Рынок, Завод (яблоки судя по 2 листу, находятся там)
Потенциально на втором листе будет больше 20 "баз" как мне парсить весь лист?

Comment: Если заморочено - с помощью макросов VBA (Excel) или скриптов JS (Google-таблицы). Если проще  формулами - или три `ЕСЛИ()`, или допстолбцы, или тяжелые формулы массива. Покажите ссылку на таблицы, лень Ваши данные создавать

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gaUXrJzsCVr7iQ4j20jsndQ7JQ6n6LfOYU6-KijCq-k/edit#gid=1905240203 вот тут данные. вот думал про скрипты App scprits

Comment: База не структурирована -- задача не имеет качественного решения. Для начала просто разверните данные в три колонки: `[Место]` - `[Тип]` - `[Продукт]`

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, что можно придумать - три одинаковых функции для разных диапазонов:

```
=TRIM(IF(COUNTIF('база'!$A:$B;A2);'база'!$A$1&" ";"")&IF(COUNTIF('база'!$D:$E;A2);'база'!$D$1&" ";"")&IF(COUNTIF('база'!$G:$H;A2);'база'!$G$1&" ";""))
```

Comment: хм, а я могу так парсить весь лист?просто надо масштабировать второй лист до 20 таких "баз" и даже больше

Comment: А где раньше было написано про '20 таких "баз" и даже больше'? В таблице было только три... Написать формулу с 20-ю блоками :)  Ждите, может, кто скрипт напишет.

Comment: Извините, допишу