# Вывод заголовков столбов

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста формулу для гугл таблиц которая будет искать в каких столбцах на листах "base" "fix" "shop" содержится слово из ячейки A10 и выводить списком через запятую заголовки этих столбцов в одну клетку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дубль вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561233/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

```
= JOIN("";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
СЦЕПИТЬ(
  ЕСЛИ(
    ЕЧИСЛО(НАЙТИ(B3;'base'!$A$1:$Z$100));
    'base'!$A$1:$Z$1 & ", ";
    ""
  )
)
 );
  1;
  ЧИСЛСТОЛБ('base'!$A$1:$Z$1)
);     ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    СЦЕПИТЬ(
      ЕСЛИ(
        ЕЧИСЛО(НАЙТИ(B3;'fix'!$A$1:$AO$100));
        'fix'!$A$1:$AO$1 & ", ";
        ""
      )
    )
  );
  1;
  ЧИСЛСТОЛБ('fix'!$A$1:$AO$1)
);ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    СЦЕПИТЬ(
      ЕСЛИ(
        ЕЧИСЛО(НАЙТИ(B3;'shop'!$A$1:$BA$100));
        'shop'!$A$1:$BA$1 & ", ";
        ""
     )
   )
  );
      1;
      ЧИСЛСТОЛБ('shop'!$A$1:$BA$1)
);)
```

решил подобной формулой